# Ruby on Rails and Sendinblue via SMTP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sendinblue

I would like to use Sendinblue to send transactional email from my Ruby on Rails web application via SMTP.
I edited `config/environments/production.rb` as follows:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address => 'smtp-relay.sendinblue.com',
  :port => '587',
  :authentication => :plain,
  :user_name => ???,
  :password => ???,
  :domain => 'fireworks.com',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

What am I expected to use as `user_name` and `password`? My account's username and password or my SMTP keys? Also, am I required to use any gem, like `sib-api-v3-sdk`, or this gem is useful only for sending email using the Sendinblue API?

Comment: You can find your password and username in the settings tab on the sendinblue site. No, you don't need an additional gem to send mails with SMTP. Rails does not care what SMTP server you're using. But I would really consider using the API instead of SMTP.

Comment: In the settings tab there are only general settings, like timezone.

Answer (score 10):

Simply go to your SendInBlue account's API page and use the the username and password found there.

https://account.sendinblue.com/advanced/api

Other answers suggest to use gems that are not required for SMTP.  You **DO NOT** need the `sendinblue` or `sib-api-v3-sdk` gems to use SIB with ActionMailer in a plain vanilla Rails app.

```
#config/environments/production.rb

config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address        => ENV.fetch('SMTP_HOST', 'smtp-relay.sendinblue.com'),
  :port           => ENV.fetch('SMTP_PORT', '587'),
  :authentication => :plain,
  :user_name      => ENV['SMTP_USERNAME'], #See: https://account.sendinblue.com/advanced/api
  :password       => ENV['SMTP_PASSWORD'], #See: https://account.sendinblue.com/advanced/api
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your gemfile

```
gem 'sib-api-v3-sdk'
```

Add this to config/environments/production.rb

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: "your_domain.com", port: 587 }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address => "smtp-relay.sendinblue.com",
    :port => 587,
    :user_name => ENV['SEND_IN_BLUE_USERNAME'],
    :password => ENV['SEND_IN_BLUE_PASSWORD'],
    :authentication => 'login',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

Add this in in config/initializers/send_in_blue.rb

```
SibApiV3Sdk.configure do |config|
  config.api_key['api-key'] = ENV["SEND_IN_BLUE_API_KEY"]
end
```

Make sure your environment variables are correct. It works for me in production.

Comment: I've set this up without the Ruby gem.  Its just plain old SMTP authentication and doesn't need their SDK to do it.

Answer (score -1):

can add `gem 'sendinblue'`Official [Sendinblue](https://github.com/mailin-api/sendinblue-ruby-gem) provided API V2 Ruby GEM

#### In order to send an email, you need to change the smtp settings in `config/environments/*.rb`(Whichever applicable)

```
Rails.application.configure do
  #append this settings
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address => ‘smtp-relay.sendinblue.com’,
    :port => 587,
    :user_name => ‘YOUR_SENDINBLUE_EMAIL’,
    :password => ‘YOUR_SENDINBLUE_PASSWORD’,
    :authentication => ‘login’,
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
end
```

change STMP & API in Your setting account

```
STMP SERVER --> smtp-relay.sendinblue.com
port --> 587
```

Comment: I have the same problem and this is not working for me either. I get `ArgumentError: SMTP-AUTH requested but missing secret phrase` in `/app/vendor/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/smtp.rb:780:in `check_auth_args'`. Any idea?

Comment: You don't need the gem when using SMTP authentication.